# How can I convert milliseconds to Julian Day Number in Java?

Tags: java, julian-date

I need a Java method that converts from "elapsed milliseconds since the beginning of the Unix Epoch" to "Elapsed days since January 1, 4713 BC". Is this functionality already implemented is Java?

I have tried several options. Some of them don't compile. Some of them are incoherent with the conversions available on line (http://www.onlineconversion.com/julian_date.htm). So, please, post only answers that you have satisfactorily used yourselves.

Comment: Have you tried with [Time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Time.html) class?

Comment: You would need to use [JodaTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/index.html) - there is no implementation for a `JulianCalendar` in the JDK.

Comment: Is there any sample code showing how to import and use the functionality?

Comment: @Josep - there is a code sample on the [Joda Time Julian Calendar page](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/cal_julian.html). Include the joda jar's by downloading them, or pulling them into your project with Maven.

Comment: **Java 8 and later** does indeed have some limited built-in support for this Julian calendar. See [my Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42081407/642706) below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [JDateTime](http://jodd.org/doc/jdatetime.html) from [Jodd](http://jodd.org). This is date-time class that performs all its calculations over *Julian Date Numbers*. **JdateTime** class has friendly user interface and any time you can get the value of Julian Date. For example, you can instantiate the class with epox milliseconds and then read the Julian Date Number:

```
JDateTime jdt = new JDateTime(milliseconds);
JulianDateStamp jds = jdt.getJulianDate();
// or:
double jdn = jdt.getJulianDateDouble()
// or:
int jdn = jdt.getJulianDateNumber()
```

If you are interested in concrete calculation, see method [TimeUtil#toJulianDate](https://github.com/oblac/jodd/blob/master/jodd-core/src/main/java/jodd/datetime/TimeUtil.java#L181). It is based on proven astronomical algorithm, but it also takes care about calculation errors of floating-points. Thats why the result is **JulianDateStamp**, class that separately holds JD integer and its fraction, to provide precision up to 1 millisecond. This class also has many test cases written.

Comment: Looks good. What's the name of the package? Where can I download it?

Comment: The full class name is **jodd.datetime.JDateTime**. It is part of **jodd-core** module. You have various options for download: http://jodd.org/download/index.html

Comment: Sorry. My analyst and me had some trouble accessing the repository, so I eventually chose another option.

Comment: The repository is on GitHub, that works quite good. If it doesn't work, you have the Maven central repo, where you can download both binary and source jar; even if you don't use Maven. And finally, you can download binaries directly from the website. Not to mention that for any reason you can contact support. I do not understand your decision.

Comment: It was probably my fault; I don't deny that. And your commitment to help surely deserves at least an up vote, so here you are. I just feel it's somehow dishonest, by my part, to accept your answer if I was unable to use it.

Comment: It's not about the votes in [SO] - it's about the open-source:) I still don't understand you saying 'I was/am unable to use' with so many options and READMEs available (github and maven are so common places today for sharing source); not clarifying what is exactly the problem with the repo. Anyhow, from my view, it make sense to *grow* the existing, maintained and tested open source (that seems to be a solution for you); then to take some simple online example. If you like, i can send you all sources on your personal email; just contact me.

Comment: Take in consideration that "milliseconds" must be a "long" variable, not a "Long" object. I tried to edit the answer to reflect this fact, but the edit was rejected with 3 votes against 1.

Answer (score 2):

The method posted here has essentially solved my needs: http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0506.html#comment-811614512
You have to take in consideration that it returns the time at noon (12:00 UTC), which is one day later than the date at midnight (0:00 UTC).

To convert from milliseconds to (year, month, day) - which is the format the aforementioned method expects -, you may use these instruccions:

```
  Date date = new Date(longMillis);

  Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
  calendar.setTime(date);

  int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
  int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1; // El mes que devuelve Calendar va de 0 a 11.
  int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
  int[] ymd = new int[] {year, month, day};
```

Comment: This code just uses the date (year, month, day) and does not count the time component (hour, minute, second, millisecond).

Comment: Again, your observation is right. But I felt that converting to (year, month, day) was much easier than converting to Julian Day Number. That's why I found the aforementioned method very useful.

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

```
Instant.ofEpochMilli( millisSinceJavaEpoch )                   // Moment in UTC.
       .atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC )                             // `OffsetDateTime` object.
       .getLong( java.time.temporal.JulianFields.JULIAN_DAY )  // `long` such as 2457811.
```

## java.time

Java 8 and later comes with the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes, supplanting the troublesome old legacy date-time classes. See [Oracle Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

> "elapsed milliseconds since the beginning of the Unix Epoch"

If you mean the epoch of first moment of 1970 in UTC (`1970-01-01T00:00:00Z`), then we can convert your count-of-milliseconds into a `Instant` object. The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) (up to nine (9) digits of a decimal fraction).

```
long millisSinceJavaEpoch = Instant.now().toEpochMilli() ;  // Simulating your given number of milliseconds since 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z.
```

> 1488099298325

```
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli( millisSinceJavaEpoch );  // Convert from number to `Instant` object.
```

> 2017-02-26T08:54:58.325Z

We need a date from that `Instant`. I'm no expert on Julian chronology, but it seems that by convention people use [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) in mapping to the modern ISO 8601 chronology. So let's convert that `Instant` to a `OffsetDateTime` with the offset constant `ZoneOffset.UTC`.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = instant.atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC );  // Convert from `Instant` to `OffsetDateTime` with UTC as assigned offset.
```

> 2017-02-26T08:54:58.325Z

From the `OffsetDateTime` we can access a [`TemporalField`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalField.html#getFrom-java.time.temporal.TemporalAccessor-). As our implementation of `TemporalField` we want [`JULIAN_DAY`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/JulianFields.html#JULIAN_DAY) constant from the [`java.time.temporal.JulianFields`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/JulianFields.html) class.

```
long jd = odt.getLong( java.time.temporal.JulianFields.JULIAN_DAY );  // Convert to Julian Day (number of whole days since January 1, 4713 BCE in the Julian calendar, a.k.a. -4713-11-24 Gregorian).
```

> 2457811

This result matches the result given at [the web site you mentioned](http://www.onlineconversion.com/julian_date.htm).

See this [code above run live at IdeOne.com](http://ideone.com/Wyx2v4).

Depending on your definition, you may want [`MODIFIED_JULIAN_DAY`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/JulianFields.html#MODIFIED_JULIAN_DAY) instead of [`JULIAN_DAY`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/JulianFields.html#JULIAN_DAY).

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) and [**SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), andfz [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

---

## `org.threeten.extra.chrono.JulianChronology`

Those java.time classes are extended by the [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project. That project includes a [proleptic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proleptic_calendar) implementation of the [Julian calendar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_calendar) system, [`JulianChronology`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/chrono/JulianChronology.html).

Answer (score 1):

```
    Time time = new Time();
    time.setToNow();
    long currentTime = Long.parseLong("1484903678788");
    int currentJulianDay = Time.getJulianDay(currentTime, time.gmtoff);
    System.out.print(currentJulianDay); // 2457774
```

Comment: Are you missing an `import` statement?  Without that, it's unclear which `Time` you are using!  It's also not obvious why you're using the `gmtoff` for "now" with a `currentTime` that's not "now".

Answer (score 0):

```
    GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
    cal.setTimeInMillis(millis);        
    cal.setGregorianChange(new Date(Long.MAX_VALUE));
    int julianDay = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);
```

Comment: No. That's not what I'm looking for. I need the astronomical Julian day number. Sorry.